# Organizing teams by ability levels by using T-SQL but one team is of mixed ability level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a table that displays teams by ability levels. One is all beginners, another is all advanced and a third is composed of beginners and advanced.

```
Team       Ability_Level  
------------------------
Team 1     Beginners.  
Team 2     Advanced.  
Team 3     Beginners.  
Team 3     Advanced.  
Team 4     Beginners.  
Team 4     Advanced.  
Team 5     Advanced.
```

The result should be:

```
Team 1  Beginners  
----------------------
Team 2  Advanced  
Team 3  Advanced  
Team 4  Advanced  
Team 5  Advanced
```

Teams with all "advanced" or with "beginners and advanced" display as "advanced." The teams with only "beginners" will display as "beginners."

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another option  -- Not clear if you want Team 1

**Full Disclosure:**  GMB's aggregation will be more performant  (+1)

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order by row_number() over (partition by Team order by Ability_Level)
```

**Returns**

```
Team    Ability_Level
Team 1  Beginners       --<< Team 1 is just beginners
Team 2  Advanced
Team 3  Advanced
Team 4  Advanced
Team 5  Advanced
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked exactly as I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

For this dataset, aggregation can do:

```
select team, min(ability_level) ability_level
from mytable
group by team
having min(ability_level) = 'Advanced'
```

Why this works is because, string-wise, `'Advanced'` is smaller than `'Beginner'`. So if a group contains both levels, `min()` gives priority to `'Advanced'`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the query but it still pulls teams with beginners. When a team is of "beginners and advanced" that team cannot also be displayed or counted in the "beginners" team or the "advanced" team. I've tried many different SQLs but so far I've had no luck.

Comment: @SonariaViztorica: I sligthly modified the query. This will produce the results that you expect for your sample data.

Comment: The modified query works as I need it to also. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

(Select Team , Ability_Level, Replace(Ability_Level,"beginners and advanced","advanced") as New_Ability_Level
from your_table
group by Replace(Ability_Level,"beginners and advanced","advanced") as New_Ability_Level
order by Team )

Teams with all "advanced" or with "beginners and advanced" display as "advanced." The teams with only "beginners" will display as "beginners."